# Method Inheritance and invoking

Tags: java, inheritance

I need to inherit an instance method from the superclass but I am stuck.

```
public class Pay

private float hours;
private float rate;
private int hrsStr;
float gross;
double tax; 

public void calc_Payroll()
{
    if (hrsStr != 0)
        gross = hrsStr + ((hours - hrsStr) * 1.33f) * rate;
    else
        gross = hours * rate;
}

public void tax(double a)
    {
    if (gross <= 399.99)
                tax = .92;
                else
                    if (gross <= 899.99)
                        tax = .88;
                    else 
                        tax = .84;
    }
```

this is the part of the super class, i need have the same method signature(???) was well as invoke tax(double a) and calc_payroll()

this is what i had for the sub class but it wasn't working.

```
public class Payroll extends Pay
{
float net;
void calc_payroll()
    {               
    float finaltax = (float) tax;   
    net = gross * finaltax;

    }

}
```

Comment: @Override isn't necessarily required, but it is recommended. The real problem is that you don't have the same accessibility or spelling of the method you are trying to override. (*public*, *calc_Payroll* with capital *P*)

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi, no the method will be overridden if the signature is the same; the @Override annotation isn't the magic fix. That said, it's good practice to have there. The problem is the subclass's method is A) not the same case-wise as the super class, and B) reduces the visibility of the super method to package level. It must be declared as `public void calc_Payroll`

Comment: It was just a comment guys but thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there are any users named Override and how often they get pinged.

Answer (score 2):

Your void calc_payroll() in your sub class does not either override or invoke the super class method.

If you want to override the method in your base class, the method signature must be the same. Use the @override annotation for clarity.

```
@override
public void calc_Payroll(float a, float b, int c, float d)
{
}
```

If your new method has a different signature, then you can call the super class method using....

```
void calc_payroll()
{
   super.calc_Payroll( ... );
}
```

Depends what behaviour you require in your new method and if you want to invoke the behaviour in the super class method.

Comment: what i am trying to do is to use calc_payroll to calculate the net pay in the subclass.  SO I want it to invoke the tax method and the calc_payroll method to calculate and return the net pay

Comment: What is the purpose of the arguments float a, float b, int c, float d? They don't appear to be used,

Comment: I just realized that I don't need those arguments as they are from private instance variables.

Comment: Removing the args will match the method signature, so your base method will now override - use the super keyword to invoke the super class methods from your base class

Comment: can i use more than one super, as I also need to use the tax method from the super

Comment: And use the same syntax if you like to overide 'public void calc_Payroll' in  class Payroll

Comment: @Kiotzu It would be easier and much more clear to make a new name for one of two of your methods and then call both of the super methods in the correct way (`this.calc_Payroll()`, `this.tax()`) : you could rename the super method as `calculateGrossPay`, then call `calculateNetPay` in the child class which calculates the gross and tax (and combines) If your `Pay` class also needs to `calculateNetPay` you could have that method also in the super (for a total of three), which only include the `GrossPay`